# adding one exception to url rewriting

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file contents:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=((?![^&]*?edit)[^\s&]+) [NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This rewrites URLs such as this:
http://domain.com/index.php?p=Contacts&ms=m5&l=en&

into this: 
http://domain.com/Contacts

and it also excludes URLs that contain the word "edit" at the end of the variable p, such as this:
http://domain.com/index.php?p=Contactsedit&l=en

I would like to add one more condition for exclusion to my .htaccess file, which is to also exclude urls that contain the word "admin" in the variable p, such as:
http://domain.com/index.php?p=admin

Could you guys give me a hand with the modification of the condition or with the addition of an exclusion condition?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your first condition like so:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=(?!admin)((?![^&]*?edit)[^\s&]+) [NC]
```

`(?!admin)` is a negative lookahead that asserts that what follows is not `admin`.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)